# C List incorrect checksum for object being freed

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C Struct for a resizing array and am getting the error:

```
a.out(34254,0x7fffa17b7340) malloc: *** error for object 
0x7fdd39c02908: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was 
probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    34254 abort      ./a.out
```

This is the code I currently have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct List {
    int length;
    int *vals; // This should be generic somehow
    int curr_inserted;
    int max_allowed; 
} List; 

List *initialize(int val) {
    List *curr; 
    curr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    if (curr == NULL) {
        printf("Memory Allocation Error\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        curr->length = 1; 
        curr->vals = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
        curr->vals[0] = val; 
        curr->curr_inserted = 1; 
        curr->max_allowed = 10; 
    }
    return curr; 
}
void add(List *x, int val) {
    if (x->curr_inserted == x->max_allowed) {
        int* bigger_arr = realloc(x->vals, (2 * x->max_allowed));
        x->vals = bigger_arr;
        x->max_allowed *= 2;
    }
    x->vals[x->curr_inserted] = val; 
    x->length++;
    x->curr_inserted++;
}
```

And I am initialzing and checking the values like this:

```
int main() {
    List *x = initialize(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        add(x,i); 
    }
    for (int i =0; i < x->length; i++) {
        printf("val %d is %d\n",i,x->vals[i]);
    }
    free(x);
    return 0; 
}
```

I believe the error is in the add method where I attempt to resize, but I can not quite figure out how to approach this error.

Comment: Where does `malloc(5 * sizeof(int))` come from? I don't see any array of 5 ints anywhere.

Comment: I was on that too, are you guessing that a pointer is twice the size of `int`? `curr = malloc(sizeof(*curr));`

Comment: There are too many magic numbers. The `10` used twice in the `initialize` function is unrelated to the `10` passed to that function? Suppose you want `20`- which `10`s do you find/replace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int* bigger_arr = realloc(x->vals, (2 * x->max_allowed));
```

will be

```
int* bigger_arr = realloc(x->vals, (2 * x->max_allowed*sizeof(int)));
```

But the way you `realloc` is wrong, given that `realloc` may fail also. You should check what it returns before you assign it.

Also `curr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));` will be 
`curr = malloc(sizeof(List));` because *for strutures you can't calculate the allocated memory it would need by adding size of individual member elements*. There is always a possibility of having padding in which case it would fail.